# Automatically enable trace flag after server restart

Tags: sql-server, trace-flags

We would like to permanently enable a trace flag on a server. I know that it is an option to add start-up parameters in SQL Server Configuration Manager. Is there any option to do it automatically after server restart via procedure/function/other solutions?

We would like to give visibility of trace flags (and options for enable/disable) to a team that will not have access to SQL Server Configuration Manager and does not have `sysadmin` level permissions.

We were thinking about a job executed as a `sysadmin` group user after server restart (not sure If it is possible) . Job could have a step executing a procedure with code such as `DBCC TRACEON (7412)`  etc.

Comment: The team already has trace flag visibility using `DBCC TRACESTATUS`. What trace flags does your non-DBA team need to enable/disable? Permitting any arbitrary trace flag is very dangerous but your DBA might be ok with delegating a whitelist of certain flags.

Comment: Being able to do it with SQL itself is also helpful for deployment automation; unless I'm missing something, setting the startup parameters doesn't lend itself to scripting, and having someone manually mess around with SQL configuration manager on multiple servers is tedious and error prone

Answer (score 6):

> We would like to enable permanently enable Trace Flag on server.

In SQL Server there are three scopes as which trace flags can be set. These are at the global level, query level and session level as outlined in the following documentation:

> In SQL Server, there are three scopes at which trace flags can work: query, session, and global. Query trace flags are active for the context of a specific query. Session trace flags are active for a connection and are visible only to that connection. Global trace flags are set at the server level and are visible to every connection on the server. Some flags can only be enabled as global, and some can be enabled at either global or session scope.

<sup>***Reference:** [DBCC TRACEON - Trace Flags (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=In%20SQL%20Server%2C%20there,global%20or%20session%20scope.) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

The you have to abide by a couple of rules which are:

> - A global trace flag must be enabled globally. Otherwise, the trace flag has no effect. We recommend that you enable global trace flags at startup, by using the -T command line option. This ensures the trace flag remains active after a server restart. Restart SQL Server for the trace flag to take effect.
> - If a trace flag has either global, session or query scope, it can be enabled with the appropriate scope. A trace flag that is enabled at the session level never affects another session, and the effect of the trace flag is lost when the SPID that opened the session logs out.

Trace flags are set on via a `DBCC TRACEON(traceflag,[-1])` and turned off via a `DBCC TRACEOFF(traceflag, [-1])`. Or in a query using `QUERYTRACEON` and `QUERYTRACEOFF`. Startup traceflags are added to the SQL Server startup via the `-T traceflag` setting in the SQL Server Configuration Manager (recommended).

> - Using the DBCC TRACEON and DBCC TRACEOFF commands.
>   For example, to enable the 2528 trace flag globally, use DBCC TRACEON with the -1 argument: `DBCC TRACEON (2528, -1)`. **The effect of enabling a global trace flag with DBCC TRACEON is lost on server restart.** To turn off a global trace flag, use DBCC TRACEOFF with the -1 argument.
> - Using the -T startup option to specify that the trace flag be set on during startup.
>   The -T startup option enables a trace flag globally. **You cannot enable a session-level trace flag by using a startup option.** This ensures the trace flag remains active after a server restart. For more information about startup options, see Database Engine Service Startup Options.
> - At the query level, by using the QUERYTRACEON query hint. The QUERYTRACEON option is only supported for Query Optimizer trace flags documented in the table below.

#### Answering Your Questions

> We would like to get access of visibility of trace flags (and options for enable/disable) to team which which will not have access to SQL Server Configuration Manager.

- You can't set a global trace flag without using the recommended SQL Server Configuration Manager or informing the resident DBA and requesting a change (Request for Change --> Change Request) according to the company's processes.
- You can't set a trace flag at the global level, if is not supported at that level, or if you don't have adequate permissions.  (See the list in the linked reference, on whether a trace flag is to be set at a global, session or query level).
- Probably most important: *...as with any configuration change in SQL Server, it is always best to thoroughly **test the flag in a non-production environment** before deploying.*

#### Additional Permissions Required

To turn trace flags on or off with the `DBCC TRACEON()` command requires the `sysadmin` fixed server role assigned to your account:

> Requires membership in the sysadmin fixed server role.

So, without the permission of the resident DBA, there will be no configuration changes on the SQL Server which is a good thing, as setting trace flags can have a negative impact on the performance of the SQL Server instance.

<sup>***Reference:** [DBCC TRACEON (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Requires%20membership%20in%20the%20sysadmin%20fixed%20server%20role.) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't appear to be a need for this because the team can already run:

```
DBCC TRACESTATUS;
```

Anyone in the **public** role can run [`DBCC TRACESTATUS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-tracestatus-transact-sql#permissions).

---

Still, if you really want to pursue this:

You can use [`sp_procoption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-procoption-transact-sql) to set a stored procedure to run automatically when the instance starts up.

> Startup procedures must be in the **master** database and cannot contain `INPUT` or `OUTPUT` parameters. Execution of the stored procedures starts when all databases are recovered and the "Recovery is completed" message is logged at startup.

For example:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SetTraceFlags
AS
    DBCC TRACEON (7412, -1);
GO
EXECUTE sys.sp_procoption
    @ProcName = N'dbo.SetTraceFlags',
    @OptionName = 'startup',
    @OptionValue = 'on';
GO
```

When the instance restarts, you will see log entries like:

[image: log entries]

Running `sp_procoption` also sets the server configuration to scan for start-up procedures, but in case anyone ever resets it zero, you can reenable it with:

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_configure
    @configname = 'show advanced options',
    @configvalue = 1;

RECONFIGURE;

EXECUTE sys.sp_configure
    @configname = 'scan for startup procs',
    @configvalue = 1;

RECONFIGURE;
```

Start-up procedures are identified by the `is_auto_executed` column of [`sys.procedures`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-procedures-transact-sql).